# Access to EntityMamanger in Spring boot from arbitrary bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How can I access the EntityManager from an arbitrary bean in Spring Boot? 
By arbitrary I mean not a service or repository bean. 
I tried this:

```
public class CriteriaFinder<T extends IdentityOwner> {
    // THIS DOES NOT WORKS
    @Autowired
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public  List<T> find(List<QueryParameter> parameters, Class<T> clazz) {

        if(em == null)
        {
            logger.error("Entity manager is null in finder");
            return null;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

I tried with/without @Autowired and @PersistenceContext annotations and with both.

(I want to use the criteria finder with containment to implement  custom find)

In a custom @Repository implementation I can access the EntityManager:

```
public class CustomerRepositoryImpl implements CustomerFinderRepository {
    // THIS WORKS
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    ...
}
```

I assume it has something to do with the way Spring is finding and initializing beans. I would also like to avoid passing the EntityManager with a constructor or setter.

Comment: how do you initialise CriteriaFinder bean - using which annotation?

Comment: With no annotation. Using new CriteriaFilter()

Comment: you have to initialise it using Spring, only then Spring can autowire the entity manager. Using 'new' creates teh object outside Spring container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may inject `@PersistenceContext` and any Spring bean in general in any class while this class is a Spring bean.
You have some tips to bypass this rule. For example by using `ApplicationContextAware`  but this should be used only in corner cases.

So make `CriteriaFinder` a Spring bean or pass it to the `EntiyManager` as parameter in the constructor.
The first way is advised if you want to take advantage of Spring features such as transactions management as you manipulate the `EntiyManager` instance.

Comment: Right, I realize this now. What throw me off was the same code (with the @PersistentContext annotation) is working for the custom repository. I missed the repository is also created by Spring.